# Calculate time stamp from date and time given by user

Tags: php

In my application, the user gives 2 inputs — one is `date` and the other is `time`:

```
$date = date("d-M-Y");
$time=date("h:m:s");
```

How can I calculate a time stamp from these two variables in PHP?
actually i take the date form date picker and time from time oicker.....

Comment: what format are you wanting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If you want time stamp then use this

echo strtotime($date.' '.$time);
```